# Copy a word and paste the same word at multiple places in Vim

Tags: cut-copy-paste, gvim

If I try to copy a word via this `yw` – yank the current word and paste it to somewhere, it works but If I try to paste it somewhere else one more time old world gets lost with previous replaced word.

I want to paste multiple times with the original yanked word.

Comment: In some cases the back hole register ([`:h quote_`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_)) can be useful to keep control over the unnamed register (possibly related http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3383/1841)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the register `0`. It contains the last yanked text.

By default, `c`, `d`, `y` use the unnamed register `""` to store all modified text.

But the numbered registers `"0` contains the previously yanked text and only that. You can use :

```
"0p
```

With confidence it will past the last yanked text.

Answer (score 2):

As of current vim (since 2022-05-06) you can use `P` in visual mode to paste over a selection without overriding unnamed register (`:h v_P`):

```
With |p| the previously selected text is put in the unnamed register (and
possibly the selection and/or clipboard).  This is useful if you want to put
that text somewhere else.  But you cannot repeat the same change.
With |P| the unnamed register is not changed (and neither the selection or
clipboard), you can repeat the same change.
```

Thus you can `yiw` to yank a word, then do multiple `viwP` replaces with that yanked word.