# How can I replace a word with a yanked word in Vi?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, replace, original-vi

Lately I've found myself working more and more with remote servers over SSH.  Most of those severs don't have Vim, but just Vi.  Using it hasn't been too rough with just a few problems.

One is this:

[How to replace a word with a yanked word in normal mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/how-to-replace-a-word-with-a-yanked-word-in-normal-mode)

The accepted answer (and the way I've always done things) uses visual mode which often isn't compiled into what I need to use (yank text, visual over text to be replace, put).

*How  can I do this in Vi?*

Comment: Did you see statox's answer? Because that seems like something that would work for you!

Comment: Use `cw` and then paste/put from your register?

Comment: Just in case, are you aware that you can open remote files with vim? See `:h scp`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes I saw it, but I was hoping for something less typey.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt doesn't `cw` overwrite the default register immediately?

Comment: @SuperScript I think it does, that's why I said put from your register (by which I meant to have your data stored in an extra register beforehand)

Comment: What about `Pde`? if you yanked the word word with something like `yw` then in most cases it will include the space after word, so if you move to another word and do `Pde` you will insert new one and erase existing. In some cases you may need `Plde` - paste, move left and then delete util the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is answered to some degree in [statox's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3376/4676) to the question you linked.

The key to your question is an understanding of [vi's *registers*](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Mp8uW2YRtsQ/TyVC1_JDanI/AAAAAAAAASI/hDfS9m7E3iY/s1600/vim_regs_p1.png).

When you yank text, it gets placed in register 0, and the *unnamed register* gets *pointed* to register 0.  When you delete text, it gets placed in register 1, and the unnamed register gets pointed to register 1.

When you "put" text, it gets pasted from the unnamed register by default.

However, you can specify what register you want to paste from or copy into.  That's what the double-quote (`"`) key does: specify a register.

So there are several simple approaches, any of which will work.  The two basic approaches are:

1. Yank the text you are going to paste just as you usually would (perhaps with `yw`, delete the text you want to overwrite just as you usually would (with `dw`), then paste *from register 0* by typing `"0P` or `"0p`.
2. Yank the text as usual with `yw`, then delete the text you want to overwrite *into the black hole register* by typing `"_dw`, then paste with `p` or `P`.

You could also yank into a named register (`"kye` to yank into register `k`, for example) and then paste from that register.

If you want the operation to be repeatable with the `.` command and perform it in one step, you could also use `"_ce` to "change to the end of the word", dumping the word being changed into the black hole register, and then type `<C-r>0<Esc>` while in insert mode to paste from register 0 and exit insert mode.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, some of the above approaches may use Vim extensions.  An approach that strictly uses [POSIX `vi` features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) but is perhaps not as handy is, yank the word you want into a named register (I'll say register k) by using `"kye`, then delete the word you don't want with `de`, and paste in the word you yanked with `"kP`.

Comment: Again, this does not work with original vi

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, how have you determined that?  POSIX specs for `vi` include registers.  (They're called "buffers" which can be confusing since there are also "editing buffers", but they're *there*.)  What part of my answer specifically doesn't work in what version of `vi`?

Comment: <c-r>0 is a vim extension. black-hole register is a vim extensions. I am not sure about register 0