# How to replace text inside () with previously yanked text?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, register

Assume I have the text `Fnord` yanked before and that my cursor resides on the `B` of the line:

```
M:mock(Baz)
```

How can I change the text inside () with the previously yanked text?

Currently, I often make the mistake by doing:

- `di(` aka "delete inside ()"
- SHIFT+P

yet which leaves me with the exact text again, as the deleted text will be moved to the register.

I want to have:

```
M:mock(Fnord)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a word with a yanked word in normal mode](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/how-to-replace-a-word-with-a-yanked-word-in-normal-mode)

Comment: @Rich The provided question covers the more general case of replacing a yanked word. I think this question is a bit more specific and does not attract the same answers.

Comment: Protip: The `0` register will contain the last yanked text. `:h quote0`

Comment: The same idea from the mentioned question's accepted answer can be applied here.  With the cursor in the parentheses, simply press `vi)p`.  It is the same as in that answer, just with the `i)` text object instead of the `w` text object,

Comment: @k0pernikus I'm afraid we'll have to agree to disagree on that one. To me, the important part of both questions is the replacement, and not the text object used to apply it.

Answer (score 14):

You can use visual selection to select the text to replace, and then paste over it as follows:

`vi(p`

`vi(` selects Baz (because it is enclosed in parenthesis), `p` pastes Fnord over it.

However, this will yank Baz to the register after the paste, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you specify a register, `p` (or `P`) will use the last register that was filled. The unnamed register `""` contains the most recently yanked or deleted text (unless another register was specified, e.g. with `"ay`), but these also go into `"0` for yanks or `"1` for deletes/changes. See [registers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).

If the last text was yanked with `y` you can paste it from the `0` register with `"0P`. If it was deleted, you could access it with the `2` register  with `"2P` (`"1` is now `Baz`).

Alternatively you could avoid messing with your registers and delete to the [blackhole register `"_`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_):

```
"_di(P
```

Answer (score 3):

If installing plugins is an option, you could use [yankstack.vim](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack). Then you could retain you current workflow:

> Currently, I often make the mistake by doing:
>
> - di( aka "delete inside ()"
> - SHIFT+P

- Alt+p  - cycle to the previous yank

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Fnord" is in register a you can do (with the cursor at the beginning of the line)
`f(ci(<c-r>a`