# How to put a word into like as if in R (type over) mode?

Tags: insert-mode

What I need to do is yank a word (yw) and then move my cursor to a diffent location and "paste" the word *over* whatever follows the cursor without disturbing the other characters in the line

"yw"
...move cursor
"p"

inserts the word. I need the put (p) to act as if it was coming from "R" mode

Comment: or https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/how-to-replace-a-word-with-a-yanked-word-in-normal-mode

Answer (score 1):

#### Replacing Several Occurrences with the Same Text in Visual Mode

I want to point out following: when you yanked and replaced the first occurrence with

```
yiw
viwp
```

and now want to repeat the replacement for another occurrence with

```
viwp
```

the inserted text is the one from the first replacement and not the originally yanked text which is something you might not want.

The default recommendation is to use the register `"0` as following

```
yiw
viwp
viw"0p
viw"0p
```

However, I often have this situation and actually want to replace even more occurences.
In this situation typing `viw"0p` felt too cumbersome and it is not dot repeateable which IMHO is a real pity.
Therefore, I was looking for a more comfortable solution which matches my expectations.

I have settled with the plugin [*ReplaceWithRegister*](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) by Ingo Karkat which provides the new operator `gr` (overrides builtin `gr`). This changes the keys to press to

```
griw
```

which is dot-repeatable. This means

```
yiw
griw
griw or .
```

**Registers: the Good, the Bad, and the Ugly Parts**

Drew Neil has discussed this matter at length:

- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/pasting-from-visual-mode/
- http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/11/registers-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-parts/
- http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/11/the-copypaste-series-a-retrospective/

Additionally to ReplaceWithRegister he points following plugins out

- https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-replace
- https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip

The latter one is now split into smaller ones

- https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-cutlass
- https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-yoink
- https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-subversive (similar to
  ReplaceWithRegister or vim-operator-replace)

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to vim, but I have a work-around for you (I think).

What worked on my machine is the following.

We start with the line:
*first second third*

Then in normal mode go to 's' of second and `yw` (to copy this word). Then go to 't' of third and delete the word with `dw`. Then use the last yanked text with `"0P`. Note the capital 'P', so that the yanked word is placed before the next.

(found this last part here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register).

**EDIT**:

My first google hit showed me this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233498/replace-word-under-cursor-vim

The solution that is used there (and better than my own solution in my opinion) is:

```
1 "This first word should overwrite the second"

yiw     yank inner word (copy word under cursor, say "first").
...     Move the cursor to another word (say "second").
viwp    select "second", then replace it with "first".
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I put the cursor over the first word and type "yiw" and then move to the cursor to the next location where I want to put the word and start typing "viwp" and after I type "vi" the characters "wp" are placed in front of my cursor as if I had just typed "i" for insert. What am I missing?

Comment: @mh2000 `v` should start visual mode; `iw` is the text object for inner word. Verify your vim has these capabilities, and make sure there aren’t any mappings at play (it sounds like the `i` is triggering insert mode, suggesting vim isn’t recognizing `iw`)

Comment: hmm... I'm using WinVi. Maybe that's a problem? When I get into work tomorrow, I'll move my files over to my Linux box and see if it acts differently there. thanks!

Comment: @mh2000 If the problem comes from WinVi, then it might make your question [off topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site. Also according to [the project page](http://www.winvi.de/en/) the developer stopped maintaining WinVi after Windows2000 (the last release was 7 years ago)... You can get much more recent version of Vim on windows which should give you less trouble.

Comment: I went to my Linux machine and tried this with the native VIM and it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Maybe I just didn't frame my question correctly. When I want to "paste" my new word (number really) over another, they are going to be different lengths, so using your suggestion in VIM, it replaces one "word" with the other, but if the first is longer than the second, it pushes everything past it to the right. If it matters, I am editing a fixed field NASTRAN .bdf file so I do not want to disturb the characters beyond my "paste". For example, if you do the yiw ... viwp to "replace" 12 with 1012, it pushed everything to the right by 2 spaces and messes up my field positions that follow it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. Maybe it can't be done in vi. If the creater of this file hadn't messed it up so badly, I would have just written an awk program to do the task, but it was too unstandard.